# How to add the taking of a parameter in AWS CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am using an AWS Serverless Function to create API events. Currently I am working on my GET event and it works the way I want it to with the given URL from AWS. I want to be able to put a / and then a number and be able to get this number. For example, it would be `myurl/1`. That number would be used to get a specific id versus the original function which gets all ID's. I am using a CloudFormation template so it needs to be something I put into the template. The event section currently looks like:

```
Events:
    GetEvent:
      Type: Api
      Properties:
        Path: /
        Method: get
```

I need to know where to add a section to be able to accept a number at the end of the path so that I can use it in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the event as follows

```
functions
  get:
      handler: myurl/get.get
      events:
        - http:
            path: myurl/{id}
            method: get
            cors: true
```

Note that above is not a part of CloudFormation [resources](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/resources/) section in serverless.yml.

Inside your event handler code in Lambda, you should be able to access the id parameter using the event object as follows

```
event.pathParameters.id
```

Refer [this](https://github.com/serverless/examples/tree/master/aws-node-rest-api-with-dynamodb) Serverless example for more details.